# JQuery fadeOut list element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I'm trying to fade out a clicked element in an ordered list.
on() seems to return the element which I can then manipulate but how do I generate the selector to actually fade out the visible li I clicked on in the HTML?
Thanks!

Here is my code, line in question is towards the bottom:

```
$("#steplist").on("click", ".step", function() {
        var stepIndex = 0;
        var li = this; // is the returned line

        //gets index of clicked line in array by looping through elements   
        while (li.previousElementSibling) {
            stepIndex++; //increments index counter
            li = li.previousElementSibling; //sets li to be next li
        }

        //sets vars to values in temp, time fields
        var temp = $("#temp").val();
        var time = $("#time").val();

        if (temp == 0 || time == 0) {
            //alert("removing step" + stepIndex);
            steps.splice(stepIndex, 1);
        } else if (temp != 0 && time != 0) {
            //needSelectorHere.fadeOut(3000, function(){
        }); steps.splice(stepIndex, 1, [temp, time]);
}
updateMash();
});
```

Comment: can u share a fiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to refer to the element you clicked on, and `$(this).index()` returns its position as a child within its parent.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdjcf77p/)

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ol>
```

JS:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).index());
  $(this).fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  Glad to get rid of my ugly indexing too!

Answer (score 1):

The selector of the clicked on element is `$(this)`

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    'marginLeft' : '100px'
  },800);
});
```

```css
div{position:relative;height:100px;width:100px;}
  #red{background-color:red;}
  #green{background-color:green;}
  #blue{background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, knew it was something simple!